# Is there a name for the precision vs sensitivity plot?

Tags: roc, precision-recall

For a particular task, instead of a standard [ROC curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) (which measures the sensitivity vs the specificity), I've found it useful to plot the precision vs the sensitivity (recall).

Is there a name for this type of plot?

Answer (score 1):

It is called precision-recall curve

Comment: I thought it may have had a special name like the Receiver Operating Curve does. If it's that simple then this answers the question!

Comment: No, there is no special name for it.